# Unable to pass variable in typewrite function in python

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a problem in passing a int variable in typewrite function under pyautogui library consider the example to have clear view

```
for k in range(13,ag19):        
    pyautogui.typewrite('f-'k)
```

I want k variable to be auto incremented but it giving the error message

Comment: `'f-'k` is not a valid python expression.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is caused by the `'f-'k` part. Did you mean to pass `'f-k'`? Can you please post the exact error message and traceback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably might need to do is to convert the int to string , as typewrite takes 
string argument : 
Refer the below sample :

```
import pyautogui
ag19 = 19
for k in range(13,ag19):        
    pyautogui.typewrite('f-'+str(k))
```

And might need to add this in the beginning after import pyautogui :

```
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1         # set pyautogui.PAUSE to 1 for a one-second pause after each function call
```